# Change border color of both divs when hover on one div in css

Tags: html, css

i have two divs and and i want if when i hover on one div, border color of both divs should be change...

CSS :

```
.uperdiv {
width:80%;
background-color:black;
margin-left:10%;
border-style:none solid none solid ;
border-width:5px; 
border-color:#fff;
border-top-style:none;
height:170px;
margin-top:-220px;
transition:border-color 2s;
-moz-transition:border-color 2s;
-webkit-transition:border-color 2s;
-o-transition:border-color 2s;
}
.uperdiv:hover + .lowerdiv{
border-color:#9900ff;
}   
.lowerdiv {
border-style:none solid solid solid ;
border-color:#fff;
border-width:5px;
background-color:black;
width:80%;
border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
height:50px;
margin-left:10%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="uperdiv">
Some text
</div>
<div class="lowerdiv">
</div>
```

I tried + sign but it changes lower div border color when i hover on uper div...and you can say that i want to create effects as of one div.
And now i have no idea.. is there any way to do it?? 
And plz don't use jquery and javascript only css and css3
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't (yet) target the *previous* sibling using CSS. You could put the two `div`s in a container, though, and apply the :hover to that.

#### html

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="upperdiv">
        Some text
    </div>
    <div class="lowerdiv">
        Some text 2
    </div>
</div>
```

#### css

```css
.container:hover .upperdiv,
.container:hover .lowerdiv {
    border-color: #9900ff;
}
```

This way, when you hover either `.upperdiv` or `.lowerdiv`, both will have the `border-color` applied.

---

We might be able to do this without the container in the future, using the [subject indicator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject)

It would look something like this;

```css
.upperdiv:hover,
.upperdiv:hover + .lowerdiv,
.lowerdiv:hover,
!.upperdiv + .lowerdiv:hover { /* target .upperdiv when the next sibling is hovered */
    border-color: #9900ff;
}
```

Comment: @MaqboolUrRahimKhan I see you accepted the answer that does the exact same as mine except posted later and with less detail. What is it you *do* want, then?

Comment: Oh got it now and now i am confusef what should i do but u did post frst so now i am accepting your answer :)

Comment: @MaqboolUrRahimKhan What part are you confused about? I made a demo here, hope it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/vxN97/

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="anyClass">

    <div class="upper">

    </div>

    <div class="lower">

    </div>

</div>
```

Css:

```
.anyClass:hover div{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Just add a container with anyClass to hold your div's
then add the css

Comment: Perfect thanks buddy :) and i dnt know why other did not agree with your answer ...Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You need to add hover for the uper div class:

```
.uperdiv:hover
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/HxtXH/)**

Answer (score 0):

Check it out:

html:

```
 <div class="upperdiv">Some text</div>
 <div class="lowerdiv"></div>
```

css:

```
   .upperdiv, .lowerdiv{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }

    .upperdiv:hover, .upperdiv:hover+.lowerdiv{
        border-color: red;
    }
```

It's kind of simplified but it's what you want.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b58CU/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.uperdiv:hover, .uperdiv:hover + .lowerdiv{
border-color:#9900ff;    
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q2Acj/)**